# Cannot set property 'id' of null (for a list)

Tags: javascript, list, modulo

The script is not able to refer to list[2] although it is working for i = 0 and i = 1.

[image: pic]

Comment: Can you please post the code here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Part of an MCVE is listing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it -- people aren't going to want to type out your code manually! ;) It would also be helpful to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: You do realize you're changing the ID so an element with ID `homeBody` no longer exists after the second iteration?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `list[i]` ... `document.getElementById()` is null

Comment: @Li357 Wow now I feel stupid, thank you :p

Answer (score -2):

Try to replace `line 5` with:

```
document.getElementById(list[i]).id = list[++i%list.length]
```

And delete `line 7`.